# Swift - Opening web view links modally

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiwebview

So I have a web view displaying a page and would like to open any links in a new view controller containing a web view modally (like twitter and Facebook do).

I have worked out how to get the url of the link clicked:

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    let youClicked = request.URL!
    print(youClicked)
    return true
}
```

But haven't managed to work out how I can pass this value into a web view on another page and present that view controller modally as a popover.

Any ideas?

Comment: `let svc = SFSafariViewController(URL: youClicked)
    self.presentViewController(svc, animated: true, completion: nil) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an out of the box component which can deal with your need. Instead you have to create your own component:

1. Create a new UIViewController and place a WKWebView in it (Can be archived by Interface Builder or Code - I usually prefer Interface Builder) . Furthermore create an outlet (e.g. called "webView") for the WKWebView
2. Create the controller - set the URL and present it
    
   `// Create the controller
   let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyCustomWebViewController")`
       
       
   `//start loading the URL
   controller.webView.loadRequest(request)`


   `// present it
   presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: There is an excellent example [here](https://github.com/Sweefties/iOS9-NewAPI-SafariServices-Example) using iOS 9.0's `SFSafariViewController` class

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at **SFSafariViewController** at [Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SafariServices/Reference/SFSafariViewController_Ref/)

In order to implement the solution you have to import **SafariServices** and after that...

1. Declare an Safari View Controller

   let destination: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://desappstre.com")!

   let safari: SFSafariViewController = SFSafariViewController(URL: destination)
2. Segue from your current view controller to the safari view controller declared on step 1

   self.presentViewController(safari, animated: true, completion: nil)

If you need control over HTTP events you can use the `SFSafariViewControllerDelegate` in your destination view controller.

Comment: This is really more of a comment than an answer.  Can you please elaborate on how using this view controller answers the question?

Comment: You're right @JAL, I'll try to develop a little *playground* about it. THX